# AsyncTask and Services that uses onHandleIntent?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a button click listener that's trigger a `Service`. that service fetches data from the web via `onHandleIntent` method.
This data is printed in my activity using a `ListView`

should i use `asyncTask` in my service(*to fetch data from the web*) or in my button listener or i shouldn't use it at all??

What are the best practices in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) it will handle each Intent received in a worker thread, so there's no need to use an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Service runs in main thread. Since you wanna fetch data by service, you should run `AsyncTask` in `onHandleIntent` method of service.